# Empty resultset when using Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Query\Builder

Tags: php, orm, phalcon

Good day, eveyrone!

I'm trying to fetch data from Oracle database via Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Query\Builder, but resultset allways empty.

```
// APPLICATION_ROOT/app/models/Package.php
<?php

use Phalcon\MVC\Model;

class Package extends Model
{
    public function getSource()
    {
        return 'RADIO_PACKAGE';
    }
}
```

The controller class:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $packages = Package::find();
    var_dump($packages->toArray()); // null

    $query = $this->modelsManager->createBuilder()->from('Package')->getQuery();
    var_dump($query->execute()->toArray()); // null

    // But the direct access to database returns rows
    $PDO = $this->getDI()->get('db')->getInternalHandler();
    var_dump($PDO->query('SELECT * FROM RADIO_PACKAGE')->fetchAll()); // returns 23 rows
}
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

I tried Phalcon 1.1.0 and 1.2.0.

PDO_OCI driver has been installed from PHP 5.4.16 source.

PHP version is 5.4.11.

Oracle version is "Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.7.0 - 64bit"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in 1.2.0 branch, discussion about the problem: http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/464/empty-resultset-when-using-phalcon-mvc-model-query-builder

Answer (score 0):

Do you have in public/index.php a setup for Loader ?
Something like

```
$loader = new \Phalcon\Loader();
$loader->registerDirs(
    array(
        $config->application->controllersDir,
        $config->application->modelsDir,
                    $config->application->pluginsDir
    )
)->register();
```

Comment: Yes of course, the problem is phalcon bug: http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/464/empty-resultset-when-using-phalcon-mvc-model-query-builder